# Creating dirset that includes the subfolders of the folders

Tags: ant, directory, subdirectory

I have a property called source-locations and it contains a comma separated list of folders where source code can be found.

```
    source-locations=src,other_src_dir,yet_another_dir
```

In one of my ant tasks I use a dirset like this:

```
    <dirset dir="${basedir}" includes="${source-locations}"/>
```

My problem is that in this case only the directories listed in the source-locations property will be part of the dirset and I need all the subdirectories of those directories as well. How can I accomplish this?

Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="path.antcontrib"/>

<target name="test">
    <property name="source-locations" value="src,other_src_dir,yet_another_dir"/>

    <!--Replace comma symbol to the `/**,` string and save new expression in to the source-locations_mod property-->
    <propertyregex property="source-locations_mod"
           input="${source-locations}"
           regexp=","
           replace="/**,"
           global="true" />

    <!--Add finally `/**` string to the source-locations_mod property. Was used var task to prevent property immutable -->
    <var name="source-locations_mod" value="${source-locations_mod}/**"/>

    <!--New source-locations_mod property was used-->
    <dirset id="source.set" dir="${root.folder}" includes="${source-locations_mod}"/>

    <!--Check the result-->
    <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}"
             property="dir.name" 
             refid="source.set">
        <mapper type="identity" />
    </pathconvert>
    <echo>Folders: ${dir.name}</echo>
</target>
```

I've used [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) and [var](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) task from [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 1):

Example below.

```
<mkdir dir="dir1" />
<mkdir dir="dir2" />
<mkdir dir="dir3" />
<mkdir dir="dir1/dir1a" />
<mkdir dir="dir1/dir1b" />
<mkdir dir="dir1/dir1c" />
<mkdir dir="dir2/dir2e" />
<mkdir dir="dir2/dir2f" />
<mkdir dir="dir2/dir2g" />
<mkdir dir="dir3/dir3h" />
<mkdir dir="dir3/dir3i" />
<mkdir dir="dir3/dir3j" />

<property name="source-locations" value="dir1,dir2,dir3" />

<pathconvert property="source-locations_mod" pathsep=",">
  <regexpmapper from="^(.*)$" to="\1/\*\*" handledirsep="true" />
  <map from="${basedir}/" to="" />
  <dirset dir="${basedir}" includes="${source-locations}" />
</pathconvert>
<echo message="source-locations_mod: ${source-locations_mod}" />

<dirset id="dirset" dir="${basedir}" includes="${source-locations_mod}"/>

<property name="dirs" refid="dirset" />
<echo message="dirs: ${dirs}" />
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't quite know how to do that (I cannot just change the value of the property in the properties file). Would you use a propertregex to add the /** part?